# using nusoap returns fault code

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

making a call to a web service method with nusoap returns an error

```
array(3) { ["faultcode"]=> string(11) "soap:Client" ["faultstring"]=> string(516) "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: . at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap11ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest() at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.RouteRequest(SoapServerMessage message) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize() at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)" ["detail"]=> string(0) "" }
```

is the fault in my calling or with the soap server?

```
    $response = $qes->call('GetXhtml',$url);

    var_dump($response);
```

Above is the call to the function, which accepts 1 parameter ($url) which I have checked as valid.

-------FULL CODE-----

```
<?php
//include nusoap class
require 'extensions/nusoap/lib/nusoap.php';

//connect to QES
$qes = new nusoap_client("https://www.qes24.com/swindon/ppa/uat/contentserver/contentserver/contentserver.asmx");
$qes->useHTTPPersistentConnection();
$qes->soap_defencoding = 'utf-8'; 

//check connection
$error = $qes->getError();

//get current page
$curl = curPageURL();//function derives current URL
$furl = $curl."?Type=8AFCCCB9-93DC-421E-A617-92A990EC99A7";
$param = array('url' => $furl);



$response = $qes->call('getXhtml', $param, '','http://tempuri.org/GetXhtml', array('content-type' => 'UTF-8'), true,null,'rpc','literal');

fb::log($response);

// Display the request and response
echo '<h2>Request</h2>';
echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($qes->request, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
echo '<h2>Response</h2>';
echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($qes->response, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';

//*/
```

The request SHOULD look like this (according to the company providing the service)

```
POST /swindon/ppa/uat/ContentServer/ContentServer/ContentServer.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.qes24.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/GetXhtml"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetXhtml xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <url> http://localhost/waggleb/?Type=8AFCCCB9-93DC-421E-A617-92A990EC99A7</url>
    </GetXhtml>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
    ?>
```

Actual Full Request made by Nusoap:

```
POST /swindon/ppa/uat/contentserver/contentserver/contentserver.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.qes24.com
User-Agent: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123)
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/GetXhtml"
Content-Length: 516

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Header><content-type xsi:type="xsd:string">UTF-8</content-type></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><url xsi:type="xsd:string">http://localhost/waggleb/?Type=8AFCCCB9-93DC-421E-A617-92A990EC99A7</url></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Full response:

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 07 Feb 2011 10:50:25 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 329

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetXhtmlResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><GetXhtmlResult /></GetXhtmlResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error that's being returned, I'd guess (but I can't be certain without knowing which API you're trying to use) that the problem is the method name. Perhaps it's cased incorrectly?  Either way, this means that the server can't direct your SOAP request to the correct module.

Comment: https://www.qes24.com/swindon/ppa/uat/contentserver/contentserver/contentserver.asmx -->here is the service

Comment: Ok, based on that, it should be working. It does seem to be in the correct casing. Can you post the rest of your code? It may be something in how you've set up the SoapClient.

Comment: It's a little different now, but still not working (getting 200 but no results). I have included what the contract SHOULD look like, according to the provider as well as my whole code.

Comment: You've got a bit of code in there to output the full request and the full response: can you paste the output from that? It'd be interesting to compare what you're sending to the actual expected request. Other than that, I have seen some issues using nusoap - are you stuck with PHP4? Otherwise, I'd recommend switching to the built-in SoapClient support in PHP5.

Comment: As you can see, the call is successful, but the results are empty (they SHOULD contain an html form)

Comment: In that case, I'd contact the providers of the service; if there is literally no data coming back after a correct response, there's probably a problem at their end.